# Writing a bootloader in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, bootloader

Is it possible to write the entirety of a bootloader for an embedded device in Python?

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is, to my knowledge, not possible. python cannot be compiled to assembly or to machine code and as such cannot be used to control the system without an interpreter. This means that you cant use python to make the boot loader without having some sort of kernel and system to handle the interpreter, which would require a boot loader to run.

Some reading into how to create your own kernel and boot-loader.
https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page